# PHP - Facebook API: Alerting the user of a change... simply enough

Tags: php, facebook

It would seem that this would be a simple thing to do, but I just can't seem to find anything on how to accomplish this on the Facebook Developer forum, the API nor Google. 
I'm using the PHP SDK to write a simple app that looks for a certain change regarding the current user (not to seem mysterious, it's just that this part is irrelevant). 
As soon as this change is detected, I want to somehow alert the current user of the change, just not by posting it to the user's wall, this information needs to stay confidential - it needs to stay between the user and the app. 
According to the Facebook API documentation, notifications are generated automatically - so I have no control over them, and I can't seem to get the Bookmark counter to update automatically either - I have to problem getting it to increment when the user visits the app canvas page and something occurs, but what I want is to alert the user of a certain event without requiring the user to actually visit the app canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guide you to the [Request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) page because it's (supposed to be) the right place to look. But as usual something is missing in the documentation.

Anyway, what you are looking for is a **application-generated request**:

```
<?php 

  $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
  $app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $user_id = THE_CURRENT_USER_ID;

  $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message=’INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG’" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";

  $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo("Request id number: ", $result);
?>
```

Described in a "[blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464)" <strike>instead of the documentation!</strike> and can be fount in this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests) (*thanks @Charles*).

Comment: BTW I forgot to mention it in my original post, but I saw the app-generated request in the documentation and couldn't get it to work using their instructions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests). I will try what you posted instead, maybe something was a bit off (either on their end or on my end). Thanks!

Comment: Ahh! I've never looked for it there! I thought they didn't mention it in the documentation! but I guess it's the same code..

Comment: Will this method check for updates/changes without requiring the user to actually visit the app canvas page?

Comment: @Charles: Checking for updates is up to you and your app implementation (cron jobs..etc) unless it's a Facebook related updates then you need the realtime api. I've seen that you've accepted the answer, mind sharing with us what was wrong? and how my answer helped?

Comment: Well first off, your answer got me thinking about "app-generated requests" again, which led me to this compact little line: 
`$facebook->api("/me/apprequests", 'post', array('message'=> 'x', 'data' => 'comment'));`
Now this is quite embarrassing, so I didn't want to mention it - but here's hoping others made the same mistake I made and this helps them out: After seeing "Requests 2.0" mentioned in a few places, I suddenly remembered it appeared in my App Settings. And sure enough, App Settings >> Advanced >> Upgrade to Requests 2.0 - was disabled. :\ Needless to say I felt silly (read "idiot").

Comment: And now I'm looking into automatic updates. Maybe cron jobs, as you mentioned. 
Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction, and big thanks to @ceejayoz too

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the PHP SDK to write a simple app that looks for a certain change regarding the current user (not to seem mysterious, it's just that this part is irrelevant).

Actually, that's not entirely irrelevant, as the Facebook TOS prevents you from doing this in most situations, especially defriending, relationship statuses, etc.

> As soon as this change is detected, I want to somehow alert the current user of the change, just not by posting it to the user's wall, this information needs to stay confidential - it needs to stay between the user and the app.

Request their e-mail and send it that way.

Comment: The e-mail idea really did come to mind, I may just end up doing it that way. 
Also, since you mentioned it, other than https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ are there any other terms I should read as a developer (that I missed)?

Comment: Facebook's documentation is horrendous, and their TOS are no exception to this. Some stuff can be gleaned from the dev forums, other stuff from their non-dev FAQ/help content.

Comment: Situations like the ones you mentioned (defriending, relationship statuses, etc.) - where does it say an app can't look for these changes, and is it specific to the current user, the current user's friends, or both? Why would Facebook let developers have access to this information but not be allowed to do anything with it?

Comment: Facebook provides that data for a whole bunch of valid uses. It can be used in ways that violate FB's desired usages, which'll get your app removed. For example: http://www.allfacebook.com/defriended-facebook-iphone-2010-01

Comment: Not to push any boundaries or get my app removed (this doesn't even apply to the app I'm currently developing), but the article you linked to mentions that "this developer violated section 2 of the Facebook Platform developer agreement which states “you must not notify a user that someone has removed the user as a friend.”"
I went over the same Policy and found no mention of this "section 2" or anything like it. The only mention of using the user's friends' info is this: "A user's friends' data can only be used in the context of the user's experience on your application."
What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like they've genericised the policy. FB's a moving target, and they often don't announce changes. Might be worth asking in their Developers forum to see if that's still in effect - they may have decided to allow it now, or they may have just decided another provision in that policy covers the situation already. I remember the argument FB provided when that was added being that unfriending shouldn't be announced to users.